# How to fetch nested JSON to table with VueJs?

Tags: json, vue.js

I need to create a table with Vue and the data are from a JSON. I don't know how to set for the td table tag the "Jogosultsagok" two "Nev" values.

I tried row.Jogosultsagok[0].Nev format, but this not work, I write down the code parts and the final error for this.

HTML

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="row in get_rows()">
    <td>{{row.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Nev}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Jogosultsagok[0].Nev}}</td>
    <td>{{row.Jogosultsagok[1].Nev}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Vue

```
data: {
  rows:[]
},
created:function() {
  fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jr55')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
    this.rows = res;
  })
},
methods: {
  "get_rows": function get_rows() {
    var start = (this.currentPage-1) * this.elementsPerPage;
    var end = start + this.elementsPerPage;
    return this.rows.slice(start, end);
  },
},
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Nev": "László",
    "Jogosultsagok": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Nev": "Módosítás"
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Nev": "Olvasás"
      }
    ],
    "Eletkor": 25,
    "Regisztralt": "2019-01-31 06:45:51.557Z",
    "Munkahely": {
      "Id": 12,
      "Nev": "Cég 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Nev": "Péter",
    "Jogosultsagok": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Nev": "Olvasás"
      }
    ],
    "Eletkor": 44,
    "Regisztralt": "2011-01-31 09:23:51.234Z",
    "Munkahely": {
      "Id": 34,
      "Nev": "Cég 2"
    }
  },
...
```

I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nev' of undefined

Comment: Can you provide your code of `get_rows()`?

Comment: I forget this part, but edited the question and added to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occures because the JSON response is not consistent: 
`row.Jogosultsagok[1]` is not always  defined as the nested Array sometimes only contains one element.

You can fix the error by leaving the table cell empty in case the value is missing:

```
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in get_rows()">
      <td>{{row.Id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Nev}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Jogosultsagok[0].Nev}}</td>
      <td v-if="row.Jogosultsagok[1]">{{row.Jogosultsagok[1].Nev}}</td>
      <td v-else></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```